How to solve this integral equation $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z)x^z dz = F(x)$ for f(x)?
My question is: solving $f(x)$ with known $F(x)$ and equation
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z)x^z dz = F(x).$$
I met this problem when I tried to extend the idea of generating functions for discrete random variables to continuous random variables.
The generating functions for discrete random variables are defined as
$$G(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n.$$
For a given $G(x)$, to obtain $a_n$, we can calculate $\left.\frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n} G(x)\right|_{x=0}$ or
$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{G(z)}{z^{n+1}} dz$
where the integral contour is the unit circle.
I checked that $\int_C \frac{F(z)}{z^{x+1}} dz$ is not the solution for $f(x)$.
For example, $\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{e^{-\frac{(y-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma^2 }}
   x^y}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma }dy=x^{\mu } e^{\frac{1}{2} \sigma ^2 \log ^2(x)}$, but $\int_C \frac{F(z)}{z^{x+1}} dz=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{-\frac{(z-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}
   \left(\text{erfi}\left(\frac{-\mu +i \pi  \sigma ^2+z}{\sqrt{2} \sigma
   }\right)-\text{erfi}\left(\frac{-\mu -i \pi  \sigma ^2+z}{\sqrt{2} \sigma
   }\right)\right)}{\sigma }$. However, the form is close to ${e^{-\frac{(y-\mu )^2}{2 \sigma^2 }}
   }$.
Besides, this problem is similar to finding the inverse transformation of an integral transformation.
Update:
I guess that
$$f(x)=\frac{i}{2\pi}\int_{-i \infty}^{i \infty} \frac{F(z)}{z^{x+1}}$$
or something similar to the above expression.
It seems true for the Gaussian distribution.
Why do I ask this question?
It seems that if the PDF of $X_1$ is $f_1(x)$ and the PDF of $X_2$ is $f_2(x)$, and their transformations are $F_1(z)$ and $F_2(z)$ correspondingly, then the transformations of the PDF of $X_1+X_2$ is $F_1(z)F_2(z)$, and the similar result for more than two continuous random variables. I'm trying to find a simple way to calculate the PDF of sums of continuous random variables.

@underflow It is similar to  Mellin transform,  but the integration variable appears in the exponent rather than the base in my question.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z)x^z dz  &=& \int_{0}^\infty f(-z)e^{-z\ln(x)} dz + \int_{0}^{\infty}f(z)e^{z\ln(x)}dz\
& =& \mathcal{L}\left[f(-z);\ln(x)\right] + \int_{0}^{\infty}f(z)e^{z\ln(x)}dz
\end{eqnarray*}
If the Laplace transform exists, I suspect the integral at the right diverges due to the exponential growth.

@Bertrand87 However, in my question $f(x)$ is a probability density function $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx =1$, and sometimes $f(x)$ is truncated, so we can assume that the integral converges.

Ok, this may work for normal or lognormal distributions. You have to be very specific in the type of function $f(z)$ otherwise the transformation won't work, for example, the exponential distribution is bounded but is only defined for $z>0$.

@Jie Zhu, This may help you. https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/resources/laplace-transform/

You are dealing with an ordinary Laplace transform by denoting $x=e^s.$  Depending of the interval $x\in [A,B]\subset [0,\infty)$ where $F$ exists you can take a fixed $s_0\in (\log A,\log B)$ and consider $g(t)=F(e^{s_0+it})$ and if you are lucky enough for getting an integrable $g$ you will get from the Fourier inversion theorem
$$h(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-izt}g(t)$$ and  therefore $$f(z) =e^{-s_0z}h(z)$$
